# Yii Collect Data For Two Or More Models ( Get_Class() Expects Parameter 1 To Be Object, Array Given )

Tags: php, templates, yii, yii-cmodel

I get this error when I call CreateController : "get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given "

Controll/actionCreate() is as follows:

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Ogrenci;
    $model2 =new Adresler;
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model, 'ogrenci-form');
    $this->performAjaxValidation($model2, 'ogrenci-form');
    if (isset($_POST['Ogrenci'],$_POST['Adresler'])) {
        $model->setAttributes($_POST['Ogrenci']);
        $model2->setAttributes($_POST['Adresler']);
        if ($model->save(false) && $model2->save(false)) {
            if (Yii::app()->getRequest()->getIsAjaxRequest())
                Yii::app()->end();
        else
            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->ogrenci_id));
        }
    }
    $this->render('create', array( 'model' => $model,'model2' => $model2));
}
```

create.php:

```
<?php  $this->renderPartial('_form', array(
    'model' => array('model'=>$model,'model2'=>$model2),
    'buttons' => 'create'));
?>
```

And _form.php's fields is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model2,'aciklama'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model2,'aciklama'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model2,'aciklama'); ?>
</div><!-- row -->
```

Comment: What line number are you getting the error on?

Comment: /framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php(2220) but it solved.
Thanks 4 edit teresko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->renderPartial('_form', array(
    'model' => array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'model2'=>$model2
    ),
    'buttons' => 'create'
));
```

code above means that file `_form.php` will have access to two variables:
$model - array of two elements, and $buttons - string.

So, to get access to first model you have to write `$model['model']`, second - `$model['model2']`.

but in this code

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model2,'aciklama'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model2,'aciklama'); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model2,'aciklama'); ?>
```

You are trying to access undefined variable `$model2`. And this should raise respective error.

The thing that error is not got makes me thinking that somewhere before listed code you access variable `$model` in the similar way, something like this:

```
echo $form->labelEx($model,'test');
```

In the above code `$model` is array(because you passed array). That is why you receive error that object is expected.

So, you should either pass models or access them in a proper way.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved another problem.Perhaps someone may be in need..

(CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key)

```
if ($model->save(false) && $model2->save(false)) {
        if (Yii::app()->getRequest()->getIsAjaxRequest())
                Yii::app()->end();
        else
            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->ogrenci_id));
}
```

to

```
  $a=$model2->save(false);
    $model->adresler_id=$model2->adresler_id;
    if ($a && $model->save(false)) {
        if (Yii::app()->getRequest()->getIsAjaxRequest())
            Yii::app()->end();
        else
            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->ogrenci_id));
    }
```